# how to make a socket listening server by make-network-process in elisp? (provide a example maybe)

Tags: elisp

I read elisp's network server manul, but I cann't find write a socket listening server. Some puzzles of the function "make-network-process":

1. How to bind the server?
2. How to accept the client connections and create a a new network process?
3. how to communicat with the client process by the new created network process?

Is there any snippet source code about network server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make-network-process` will make a listening server, binding it to the given port. For that, you just need to specify `:server t` among the keyword arguments.

Client connections will automatically be accepted and will automatically create new network processes.  Elisp code can set things up when a new connection comes in, because the `process-sentinel` function gets called when this happens.

Communication with the client happens via network-process created when the client connection was accepted.  This process will be used like any other process, i.e. via `process-filter`, `process-send-string`, ...

You can look at the `server.el` code (`C-h f server-start` should be a good entry point) for a reasonably simple example.